# wxHaskell Button State

Tags: user-interface, haskell, wxwidgets, wxhaskell

I'm writing an application using wxHaskell and I want to be able to detect the state of a button (whether or not it is pressed at any given time). I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to do this, however. First I thought that there might be a "button is pressed" attribute that I could use, but there didn't seem to be. Then I had the idea of maintaining an `IORef` which I update on button-up and button-down events. However, that would require that the `Button` object actually *have* button-up and button-down events, which is does not appear to. It is an instance of `Commanding`, but I assume that the `command` event is fired on button-up only, which isn't enough for that idea. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Workaround**

You can implement this yourself by detecting the low-level actions that trigger those events (eg. mouse button down, space bar down).

In WX you can use the following function and constructor:

```
mouse :: Reactive w => Event w (EventMouse -> IO ())
data EventMouse = ... | MouseLeftDown !Point !Modifiers
```

And, as you suggest, you could keep the state yourself in an `IORef`. My suspicion is that left button here means *main* button (right for left-handed users).

**UI design principles**

The second question, which you haven't asked by I'll answer, is whether this is good UI design.

The behaviour of a button (assuming interaction using a mouse) is that **click events** are reported when the user releases the mouse button **in the button area** *after* pressing the mouse button down in the same area. If the user moves away and releases, or presses 'Escape', there is no click.

Taking any action on a button being pressed (not clicked) would feel unnatural for users.

In practice, the only acceptable way to use this would be, imho, to take an action whose effects can **only** be witnessed after releasing and which is immediately **undone** if the click is cancelled (ie. mouse button released outside button area).

*EDIT*: Please, also, take into account that users with accessibility requirements may have OS settings enabled that affect how and when button clicks are reported (but not down/up mouse events).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to know if a `wxButton` is pressed or not because it is an abstraction of a push button which intentionally hides this implementation detail. If you need to know the button state, use a [wxToggleButton](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_toggle_button.html) instead.